# System Verilog code syntax error

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, logic-gates, system-verilog

I wrote the following code:

```
module mul3 (
    input logic[1:0] d
);
mul3_op[0]=d[0];
endmodule;
```

But when I run it using Modelsim I get the following messages:

> Error: (vlog-13069) mul3.sv(21): near "[": syntax error, unexpected
> '['.

> Error: mul3.sv(21): (vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the
> scope following 'mul3_op'. Is there a missing '::'?

Please note that line 21 is actually the last line before `endmodule` in the code above. Any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: Mybe "input logic[1:0] d," and "output logic[3:0] res" should be  "input [1:0]logic d," and "output [3:0]logic res".

Comment: @Arseniy what I wrote is correct; input appears before

Comment: You missed 'assign' before that statement.

Comment: why I need assign?

Comment: Because that's the standard syntax.

Comment: you can use always @(*) too for the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed [assign](https://www.chipverify.com/verilog/verilog-assign-statement#:%7E:text=In%20Verilog%2C%20this%20concept%20is,of%20a%20group%20of%20signals.) keyword for that concurrent statement -

```
assign mul3_op[0] = d [0] ;
```

Comment: Do I need assign too if I wrote: "mul_enable[1]=mul;"

Comment: Any assignment outside the always block need the "assign" word.

Comment: Yes if it's a continuous assignment, ie., outside always/initial blocks.